# Should the gutters be double their non-retina size if I'm developing a retina-sized Bootstrap 3 template?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, retina

I'm developing a Bootstrap 3 XS Adobe Illustrator/Photoshop template for iPhone retina.

I wanted to confirm that the standard gutter size of 30px needs to be doubled to 60px in the template due to the retina 2x dimension increase for all screen elements.

Here is a photo of the current template with the gutters and design elements bumped up 2x.

[image: 1136px x 640px iPhone Retina Bootstrap 3 12 column template build in Adobe Illustrator]

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "developing a template"? A PSD template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to double the design elements, including gutters, to get an accurate rendering of your design at a non-retina resolution.